# Expression for something being the right target / solution for something else

Tags: single-word-requests, expressions

Expression that would describe the group of things / people that are the target for the particular purpose.

> They found the customers _______ software developers.

The message that the sentence should convey is that the software developers were the right people to sell the service to.

In the sentence:

> They found solution _____ cutting down sugar consumption.

, the word **in** could be used.

**Is it suitable for the first example as well or there is a better choice?**

Comment: I don't understand why you couldn't simply use "They found the customers were software developers". Please explain.

Comment: If you want a wordier way of saying ‘‘in’‘ (or ‘‘were’‘ or ‘‘was’‘), how about ‘‘which consisted of’‘?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand the question, but it sounds like you might be looking for the phrase "target market."